# How can I use operators within Twig hashes?

Tags: hash, templating

I'm looking for documentation on how to use operators in hashes in Twig. Someone mentioned this in the Google+ support group the other day and I was unable to find any docs or examples.

```
{% set eventParams = {
  section       : 'events',
  order         : 'startDateTime asc',
  startDateTime : '>= '~now
} %}
```

If I wanted the startDateTime hash to use a range of dates, say ( `>= now` and `<= now + 5 days` ) how would I specify that in the startDateTime hash?

Is this a hash syntax that is specific to Twig?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's what you are after:

```
startDateTime : 'and', '>= ' ~ now, '<= ' ~ now | date_modify('+5 days')
```

Comment: Is there more info about this in the docs? This is super helpful to learn.

Comment: Sorry, didn't find anything in the docs. I learned about that technique in a g+ thread the other day. The only additional info I can give you is that you can also combine operators with 'or'.

Comment: How would you use an "and" with an "or" for example: ( >= now and <= now + 5 days ) || ( >= now + 10 days and <= now + 15 days ) ?

Comment: For some reason this is throwing an error for me. It doesn't seem to like the extra commas ('and, ..., ...') used within the params object declaration {}. How did you get this to work?

Comment: @DouglasMcDonald what you need to the right of the `:` is a string: `'and, >= '~now~', <= '~(now|date_modify('+5 days'))`

Comment: @MarionNewlevant for some reason it didn't like to parse the string using the | merge filter. I think maybe something in today's update may have addressed this. Regardless I ended up using an array which seemed to do the trick. [ "and", ">= " ~ from | date('U'), "< " ~ to | date('U') ]