# How do I add a second section name to this logic?

Tags: logic, conditional

I need to add a second section name to this code:

```
craft.entries.section('not homePage')
```

I can't figure out the correct formatting. I've tried:

```
craft.entries.section('not homePage,clientPage')
craft.entries.section('not homePage, not clientPage')﻿
```

How do I add a second limiter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A second limiter is added to the conditional like this:

```
craft.entries.section('and, not homepage, not clientPage')
```

Comment: We already had a [similar question](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/47/operators-in-hash/) this morning. Do you know how to combine more complex conditionals?

Comment: I'm learning. There isn't good documentation on this topic IMO.