# How to show events for "This Weekend, Next Week"

Tags: entries, datetime

Stemming from this [original post](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/168/how-do-i-show-advanced-filters-for-events) I was able to show Events using a custom date field and successfully got "Today" and "Tomorrow" events to show up.

How would I go about doing some custom Math to show "This Weekend" or "Next Week" events? I'm sure I have to first write a conditional on determine what the current Day is, but not sure the best way to do this.

Comment: You might be able to unify these ideas into a beautiful macro or plugin. I only started on the macro quest today though, hence this timid comment instead of an authoritative answer.

Answer (score 23):

Twigs [date_modify filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date_modify.html) accepts every string, which is supported by phps [strtotime()](http://www.php.net/strtotime).

These strings are called [Relative Formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php).

.

**Examples:**

In the [original post](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/168/how-do-i-show-advanced-filters-for-events) you used:

```
{% set day = date('m/d/Y') %}
{% set nextDay = day|date_modify('+1 day') %}
```

but with [Relative Formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) you can also do something like this:

```
{% set var = day|date_modify('now') %}
{% set var = day|date_modify('10 September 2000') %}
{% set var = day|date_modify('+1 week') %}
{% set var = day|date_modify('+1 week 2 days 4 hours 2 seconds') %}
{% set var = day|date_modify('next Thursday') %}
{% set var = day|date_modify('last Monday') %}
{% set var = day|date_modify('next month') %}
```

(These are equivalents of the [php-doc examples](http://www.php.net/strtotime#example-2413) )

.

So this weekend would be:

```
{% set var = day|date_modify('next Friday') %}
```

*Or Saturday, personally I start my weekends on Thursday, so it's hard to give a good example ;)*

Next weekend:

```
{% set var = day|date_modify('next Friday +7 days') %}
```

Next weekend in one year, half an hour ago:

```
{% set var = day|date_modify('next Friday +1 year -30 minutes') %}
```

Comment: Beat me to it :)  And I had no idea you could use weekday names in date_modify! Very cool.

Comment: I also just found out after reading the docs, php still surprises from time to time.

Comment: "Next weekend in one year, half an hour ago" — *finally*, I don't have to calculate this manually all the time!

Comment: How would you get the Dates in a Range though? You solution above works well for getting events on a certain day but a Weekend should show events from Friday through Sunday right?

Comment: Does this help: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/47/how-can-i-use-operators-within-twig-hashes ?

Comment: I'll take a look, looks like that post would get me what I'm after :) Thanks for all of the help!